# Passing C++ array to python

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I would like to embed python into my C++ code. In C++ I am constructing a matrix and vector and would like to use Python's Numpy to solve the linear system. In order to build up to this: I am following this example:
http://realgonegeek.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-pass-c-array-to-python-solution.html

however this particular line:    import_array ();
is not working with my code. I am getting the following error:

> 1678:144: error: return-statement with no value, in function
>   returning 'int' [-fpermissive]  #define import_array() {if
>   (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print();
>   PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to
>   import"); return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL; } }

Has anyone successfully embedded python code into their C++ code? or may know why that particular line may not work. I am using python 3.4

Comment: Your link clearly says it works for Python 3.3. Python 3.3 is very different from Python 2.7. Thus it is not surprising that the code doesn't work.

Comment: just updated. still gives me errors.

Comment: Did you manage to work this out? I have the same error...

Answer (score 0):

one of the suggestions for that:
if your matrix, vector, or array is static, you can set an argument for the c file just like this:

`program.exe -array "[[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]"`

and use strtok or substr in c/c++ for splitting the string.

or if your program dynamically uses a new matrix/vector/array you can save it to a temp file or memory(C/C++) and if all above couldn't solve your problem you may finally re-write that part of the code in C++ language.